# Create a partial using rendered html (from markdown) in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am trying to create nested collections in Jekyll and render the nested ones as partials.

I have two collection types:

- Areas (which contain many...)
- Trails

Currently I am running into issues rendering all the trails on an "areas page".  I want an area to list all trails, all of which should be pre-rendered from markdown to html, per each trail's individual layout.

However when I try to include the trail.content and list it out, the trail text comes out as unrendered markdown (I'm left with unevaluated tags like {{page.title}}, etc).

```
{% for trail in site.trails %}
   {{trail.content}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to treat a trail as a partial?  I want to instead have access to the rendered HTML content so i can inject it directly into my page, somewhat like how rails does it!

```
{% for trail in site.trails %}
   {{trail.rendered_content}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot see your code, I've made some assumptions.

If you've declared collections like this :

```
collections:
  area:
    output: true
  trails:
```

The `area` collection is processed first and `trails` collection second. So when you try to get `trails` content from `area`, you receive unprocessed code.

Now try to reverse your configuration to :

```
collections:
  trails:
  area:
    output: true
```

You get `trails` processed first, so, when you call `trails` from `area` you receive processed code.

Et hop !

Comment: Thank you so much, David!  You've made me a very happy programmer.

On a side note, I have to use trail.output as opposed to trail.content (previously the output portion of the hash was set to nil, following your config suggestion fixed that!)

Comment: Cool ! I'll be interested to see the final result. The word `trail` sound good to me.